# VS2013 - how do you add existing xaml+vb files to a new project?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I want to move a big pile of code to a separate project and use it as a framework for where it came from.. and other stuff too.

I started a new vb.net wpf project and started adding files from the old project but when they get added, the wpf and its associated vb file are treated as separate things. What I mean is that when I add a new wpf usercontrol file(or whatever), the vb file gets nested in the xaml file but when adding existing, they get added side by side.

I'm not sure whether they work or not, still a lot to add and a little bit to rewrite but I'd like to do this properly from start to finish. Is there a more appropriate way to do this? Or if not then how would i nest the vb files into the xaml files?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I need to add the files one by one by selecting the xaml one, then it automatically adds the .vb as nested.

Comment: Thanks so much for figuring this out.  Hard to understand why this is the only way.  I'm converting an old project to VS13 and it's a giant pain in the behind.